# What is a pointed connected groupoid?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, groupoids

[Here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pointed+connected+groupoid) it says a pointed connected groupoid is a connected groupoid that is pointed. This seems nonsensical: connected groupoids don't have a terminal object, except for the trivial case. The link in nlab about pointed objects only talks about categories with terminal objects so it doesn't help.

What is a pointed connected groupoid?

Comment: A pointed groupoid is a groupoid with a chosen point (= object). The category of groupoids has a terminal object and you can see this as a special case of the general notion of pointed object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed up category levels; the definition of pointedness is about the terminal object of the $2$-category of connected groupoids itself, which is the point $1$. Then the $2$-category of pointed connected groupoids is the [coslice $2$-category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/slice+2-category) of the point; that is, it has

- objects given by functors $f : 1 \to X$ where $X$ is a connected groupoid (this just distinguishes an object of $X$, the "basepoint"),
- morphisms $(1 \xrightarrow{f} X) \to (1 \xrightarrow{g} Y)$ given by functors $h : X \to Y$ together with natural isomorphisms $\eta : h \circ f \cong g$ (this says that $h$ preserves the basepoint, but note that "preserving the basepoint" here is itself extra data, not just a property), and
- $2$-morphisms from $(h_1, \eta_1)$ to $(h_2, \eta_2)$ (both of which are morphisms as above) given by natural transformations $\eta : h_1 \to h_2$ such that $\eta_2 \circ (\eta f) = \eta_1$ (or something like that; I don't know a good convention for representing both vertical and horizontal composition, really I should be drawing a commutative diagram here).

Then the exercise is to show that this is actually just equivalent to the category of groups, with the equivalence given by taking the automorphism group of the basepoint; in particular there are no non-identity $2$-morphisms.

Comment: I don't understand how the existence of a natural isomorphism $\eta : h\circ f \cong g$ says that $h$ preserves the basepoint. Such a natural isomorphism has only one component, and we don't even need to check any commutative diagrams because $1$ only has the identity morphism! So it would still exist even if $h$ does not preserve the basepoint... Besides, "preserving basepoint" doesn't sound like a property of a functor, as it isnt preserved by natural isomorphism. What am i missing/doing wrong?

Comment: @Carla: there's a strict version of this definition where we don't talk about $\eta$ and we just ask for $h \circ f = g$ on the nose. However, *this* definition runs into your second objection: it isn't invariant under equivalence. The non-strict version where we ask for a natural isomorphism $\eta$ *is* invariant under equivalence. And yes, you are correct that $\eta$ always exists and is always unique in this case. Of course this wouldn't be true if we were talking about not-necessarily-connected groupoids.